# Is there any online material for real world examples of Object oriented design problems?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, ooad

I want to practice solving Object oriented design problems in C++.
Is there any online material with sample real world problems and solutions using design patterns ?

I searched but i couldn't get online material. Pls help me.

Comment: Unfortunately, many real world examples share following characteristics: NDA, no time for behind the scene documents, and people forget the problems because design typically takes much less time than implementation, debugging and testing.  The best way I can think of is to join real-world project: either through internship, contracting, or full-time employment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/design